# Within a <xsl:for-each select="a/b[isRed = '1']/> how can I get the position() of all nodes that will be iterated over?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

If I have an xml structure:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <isRed> 0 </isRed>
    <name> Joe </name>
  </b>
  <b>
    <isRed> 1 </isRed>
    <name> Bob </name>
  </b>      
    <isRed> 1 </isRed>
    <name> Charles </name>
  </b>      
    <isRed> 1 </isRed>
    <name> Tiffany </name>
  </b>      
    <isRed> 0 </isRed>
    <name> John </name>
  </b>
  </b>      
    <isRed> 0 </isRed>
    <name> Tim </name>
  </b>
</a>
```

When iterating over these nodes in a for-each loop, how do I get their position WITH RESPECT to the condition: [isRed = '1']. For example, if I was iterating over

```
<xsl:for-each select="a/b[isRed = '1']>
```

How would I get the current position() for Charles to be 2 instead of 3? (Since the B node with Charles in it is the second node that matches the for-each condition. Right now, when I'm within the context of the for-each loop, if I use position() I'm getting the position of the given node with the context of the entire node list, which isn't what I want. (I need to make the xml transform into html so that the first two of the isRed = 1 is on the first page, then the rest are put on separate pages).

Also, I am not making use of template matching, but template names. I've been trying to figure this out for a day or so now, and I'm just not having any success.

Essentially, I'm trying to only loop over the first two elements in the list in the foreach loop. My actual for-each loop looks like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="a/b[isRed = '1' and position() &lt; 3]">
```

However, this is only iterating over the Joe and Bob b node, when I want it to iterate over the Bob and Charles b nodes. This is because Joe (and all other b nodes regardless of their isRed attribute or not) is being included in the position check for the for-each condition. What could I use instead of the position() call to get the actual position for nodes that meet the isRed condition?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking two separate questions to me.

Comment: How can I help clarify the question? I want to get the position() of only the nodes that are being filtered out by the condition in the for-each loop.

Comment: I am afraid you are very much mistaken. The position of Charles is 2. Or at least it would be, if the XML were well-formed and  the values weren't surrounded with spaces; `" 1 "` is **not** equal to `"1"`. -- I did not understand the 2nd part.

Comment: WRT your last part, that too is not true. `<xsl:for-each select="a/b[isRed = '1' and position() &lt; 3]">` will process Bob and Charles (again, with the same caveats as above).

Comment: @michael.hor257k you are right. I am mistaken, it is working how I originally thought it should. My xml was not formed how I thought it was, and the data I was reading from the node was causing me to believe it was reading the position of all nodes. Should I close this question as solved or delete it?

Comment: I would delete it, as it is not likely to help anyone.